# HTML + PHP функции

Tags: php, html

Привет, подскажите какая функция в PHP может так издеваться над кириллицей.
    &ETH;&agrave;&ccedil;&acirc;&euml;&aring;&ecirc;&agrave;&ograve;&aring;&euml;&uuml;&iacute;&ucirc;&eacute; &Ntilde;&aring;&eth;&acirc;&aring;&eth; .::&Iuml;&egrave;&ograve;&aring;&eth;:..

Comment: @wwwplaton, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

```
string htmlentities ( string string [, int quote_style [, string charset]] )
```

Вот описание - http://www.php.su/functions/?htmlentities

Аналогично   - http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: Спасибо большое, теперь нашел где сидит эта зараза.

Comment: Не за что) 
@wwwplaton, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).